# Rank Aggregation (local Kemenization)

Tags: r, aggregation, rank

I have two dataframes.

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Station = structure(1:9, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), class = "factor"), Dwelling_Probability = c(0.948, 
0.65, 0.592, 0.558, 0.527, 0.514, 0.494, 0.492, 0.435)), .Names = c("Station", 
"Dwelling_Probability"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(Station = structure(c(6L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
9L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I"), class = "factor"), Access_Time = c(31L, 23L, 21L, 16L, 
11L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L)), .Names = c("Station", "Access_Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Below example shows applying procedure to combine dwelling probability and access times rankings.
Ranking of dwelling probability (left) and ranking of access times (right) are aggregated to a single one (middle). i am trying to get a ranked middle dataframe

[image]

Is there a rank aggregation package which does this.

Comment: Shouldn't Station F (0.514 * 31 = 15.934) be ranked above B (0.65 * 21 = 13.65)?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The packages ConsRank (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConsRank/ConsRank.pdf) or RankAggreg (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2669484/) should serve your purpose. However, the problem of finding the consensus ranking is NP hard, so depending on the size of your data set, you might have to rely on polynomial time approximations.